# Trying to create Moq object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

I've got a method which takes a `IList<Person>` and returns an IEnumberable as so:

```
 internal static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> GetPersonsPerSite(IList<Person> Data)
    { 
         //Implementation ...
    }
```

and I'm trying to create a mock object of `IList<Person>` so I can test this method.

Using Moq I have written the following:

`var mockObjects = new Mock<IList<Person>>();`

```
mockObjects.Setup(x => x[0]).Returns(new Person()
                                                 {
                                                        SITE_ID = "test",
                                                        MPAN = "test",
                                                        ADDLINE1 = "test",
                                                        ADDLINE2 = "test",
                                                        ADDRESS_LINE_1 = "test",
                                                        ADDRESS_LINE_2 = "test"
                                                 });
```

However when I come to use the object the IEnumerable returned is aways throwing exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I'm brand new to Moq, and I'm pretty sure I'm missing a fundamental concept here, however I've successfully being able to throw exceptions and modifiy outputs with other mock objects.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mock the IList.  You don't need to, unless there's something specific your looking to check.

Instead just keep your test simple and do something like this:

```
var testData = new List<Person>(){new Person()
                                                 {
                                                        SITE_ID = "test",
                                                        MPAN = "test",
                                                        ADDLINE1 = "test",
                                                        ADDLINE2 = "test",
                                                        ADDRESS_LINE_1 = "test",
                                                        ADDRESS_LINE_2 = "test"
                                                 }};
var result = GetPersonsePerSite(testData);
```

Comment: Okay so I understand that I must be over-complicating the matter

Comment: @m.edmondson That's OK. It's easy to apply mocking to every interface you see and forget it's just there to help you deal with objects that have external interactions or are tricky to set up.  IList<T> is self contained and easy to instantiate so you might as well use the real thing.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have got there looks fine and does work for me. Can you expand with an example of where you actually consume the `mockObjects.Object` and find it null?

Also, do you really need to mock your `IList<Person>`? 
If you are just using it to supply test data to the method under test, just use a concrete list - there is nothing gained by using a mock for this.

Of course, you may be mocking it so you can verify certain actions are taken on it (methods called, properties accessed, etc) - in which case that is different.

Comment: Apologies my question is wrong, I wrote it based on memory from yesterday without checking.  The actual problem is that the IEnumberable being returned from the method causes the exception `{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}` implying I haven't set something in the Moq declaration.

Comment: Do you mean the enumerable returned by the list?

Comment: No the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>`